# Does sys.views adds huge maintenance cost to the server?

Tags: sql-server, view, sql-server-2014

I could not figure why my game being slow. But somehow by luck, i found that database has total 1451 views. I don't remember i created those

First do sql server 2014 create views automatically ?

I am using [hallengren](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html) [MaintenanceSolution.sql](https://ola.hallengren.com/downloads.html) plan daily.

It is executed as below does that create views automatically ?

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.IndexOptimize @Databases = 'Pokemon_Pets_DB',
@FragmentationLow = NULL,
@FragmentationMedium = 'INDEX_REORGANIZE,INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationHigh = 'INDEX_REBUILD_ONLINE,INDEX_REBUILD_OFFLINE',
@FragmentationLevel1 = 5,
@FragmentationLevel2 = 30,
@UpdateStatistics = 'ALL',
@OnlyModifiedStatistics = 'Y'
```

After noticing all those views, i deleted all of them. And now i see significant performance and speed increase. The total SQL server cpu usage also decreased.

What does views really do ? Why were they causing burden to my server ?

I do not have any queries that uses any views

Here a screenshot from my backup before i delete all

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> First do sql server 2014 create views automatically ?

No, it doesn't (except for certain system views which are in every database and can't be changed).

> It is executed as below does that create views automatically ?

No, his scripts do not.

> What does views really do ?

Views are definitions that are replaced inline to help facilitate code re-use and abstraction (among other things). Views are stored as a definition, nothing is persisted other than the definition unless it is an indexed view.

> Why were they causing burden to my server ?

Unless something is running against them, they have 0 overhead. Indexed views have a large amount of overhead proportional to the rate and amount of change of the base tables defined in the view.

> I do not have any queries that uses any views

Then I would set up a trace or extended event session to see who/what is creating them. Since we don't know if they are indexed views or not (since you've already deleted them) it's hard to say anything about them in general.

Comment: ty for answer what do you mean by ? "Unless something is running against them"

Comment: also i have to say that each view has several statistics.

Comment: What I mean by that is, unless something is actively querying those views, they are just metadata and nothing else.

Comment: interesting. however you see last update date. they are very recent. updating them wouldn't add overhead ?

Comment: How are you updating a view? You can change the definition but there is NO data stored on disk associated with the view EXCEPT for the sql statement (create view). Now, if it's an INDEXED view (i.e. it has indexes on it) that's a different story. Which is it?